# Extracting neccesary columns from multiple Excel files in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to extract and combine selected columns from 19 Excel files into single excel file. Am able to extract required columns from single file with below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

file = pd.read_excel("Shift Handover To A - 05-25-2021.xlsx", "25th May")

dataframe=pd.DataFrame(file[["S No", "Issue Reported By", "Shift", "Severity", "ServiceDesk Ticket #", "Issue Description", "Issue Type", "System Component", "Server Type", "Date and Time of the occurrence", "DT Observed", "Action Taken", "Worked By", "DT Action Taken", "Date and Time Resolution", "Current Stus"]])

# selecting rows based on condition
rslt_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Current Stus'] == 'In-Progress' ]

rslt_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Am trying to apply it for all files with below code,

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('')
import openpyxl
files = os.listdir(cwd)

for file in files:
    if file.startswith('Shift'):
        file = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(cwd, file))
dataframe=pd.DataFrame(file[["S No", "Issue Reported By", "Shift", "Severity", "ServiceDesk Ticket #", "Issue Description", "Issue Type", "System Component", "Server Type", "Date and Time of the occurrence", "DT Observed", "Action Taken", "Worked By", "DT Action Taken", "Date and Time Resolution", "Current Stus"]])

# selecting rows based on condition
rslt_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Current Stus'] == 'In-Progress' ]

#print(rslt_df)
rslt_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

But am receiving TypeError for dataframe=pd.DataFrame(file.....
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"
What could be wrong?

Comment: `read_excel` itself will produce a dataframe, no need to convert it to a `df` again

Comment: You use 'file' both as iterator (for file in files) and as dataframe inside the loop. Use another name instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try amend your codes as follows:

You need to define an empty dataframe and accumulate the results from each loop iteration by [`.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

No need to call for `pd.DataFrame` after the loop, you can just select the columns you want and assign it back by `dataframe = dataframe[["S No", ...]]`

```
files = os.listdir(cwd)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('Shift'):
        file_read = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(cwd, file))
        dataframe = dataframe.append(file_read) 

dataframe = dataframe[["S No", "Issue Reported By", "Shift", "Severity", "ServiceDesk Ticket #", "Issue Description", "Issue Type", "System Component", "Server Type", "Date and Time of the occurrence", "DT Observed", "Action Taken", "Worked By", "DT Action Taken", "Date and Time Resolution", "Current Stus"]]

# selecting rows based on condition
rslt_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Current Stus'] == 'In-Progress' ]

#print(rslt_df)
rslt_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is in these lines:

```
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('Shift'):
        file = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(cwd, file))
dataframe=pd.DataFrame(file[["S No", ... "Current Stus"]])
```

You use 'file' as iterator (for file in files). When the loop ends, If file.startswith('Shift') is not True, then file is a string, therefore file[["S No", ... "Current Stus"]] will throw an error.

Just use another name for the dataframe